# $lookup is not working showing non relevent record in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying use **$lookup** for two tables but after lookup i am getting non relevant records too.

**Table users**

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5c1f5fe31e11011268006aa7"),"name" : "v","email" : "v@gmail.com"},
{"_id" : ObjectId("5c1f5fd31e11011268006aa6"),"name" : "r","email" : "r@gmail.com",}
```

**TableBooking**

```
schema like 
(student_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
teacher_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' })

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c1f642aa6fb4511a0511e41"),
    "student_id" : ObjectId("5c1f5fd31e11011268006aa7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-12-23T16:02:10.179+05:30"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-12-23T16:02:10.179+05:30"),
    "__v" : 0,
}
```

**$lookup**

```
db.bookings.aggregate(
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "users",
         localField: "ObjectId(student_id)",
         foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)",
         as: "student_info"
       }
  }
)
```

**In the result I am getting both the users**

```
{
    "_id": "5c1f642aa6fb4511a0511e41",
    "student_id": "5c1f5fd31e11011268006aa7",
    "teacher_id": "5c1f5fe31e11011268006aa6",
    "createdAt": "2018-12-23T10:32:10.179Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-12-23T10:32:10.179Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "student": [
        {
            "_id": "5c1f5fd31e11011268006aa6",
            "name": "r",
            "email": "a@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c1f5fe31e11011268006aa7",
            "name": "v",
            "email": "v@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I am using localField: "student_id", ForeignField: "_id", in look up than i am getting blank student_info array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `localField` and `foreignField` are the fields from the document itself.
 What you have used **`("ObjectId(student_id)")`** is simply a String and does not exists any fields inside the document with that name.

```
db.bookings.aggregate(
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "users",
         localField: "student_id",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "student_info"
       }
  }
)
```

Comment: before I was using this but getting blank array , i update booking schema in question please take a look

Comment: I can see your `student_id` is not matching with any `_id` in your sample document. Is that the issue?

Comment: you was right ..  that was my mistake .. marking your answer right